# LINQ query computing vote count

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Items` table and `ItemVotes` table that every user can give Up vote or Down vote to an item and his/her vote determine by a `bool` property in `ItemVotes` table. Now I want to have a list of `Items` order by votes, for do this we need to get count of `true` votes minus count of `false` votes.

```
_ItemsService.GetAll(x => x.ItemVotes //here I have to order by vote)
```

**UPDATE :**

Items Entity:

```
public class Items : Entity<int>
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ItemVotes> ItemVotes { get; set; }
}
```

ItemVotes Entity:

```
public class ItemVotes : Entity<int>
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public bool TypeVote { get; set; }

    public virtual Items Items { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I use Gilad Green's answer in an action like this:

```
public ActionResult TopItems()
    {
        var items = _ItemsService.GetAllQuerable(x => x)
            .OrderBy(item => item.ItemsVote.Sum(vote => vote.TypeVote ? 1 : -1));
        return View(items);
    }
```

[image]

And here is `GetAllQuerable()` function :

```
 public IEnumerable<T> GetAllQuerable(
        Expression<Func<T,
        bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return _repository.GetAllQuerable(filter, orderBy, includeProperties);
    }
```

Comment: It will be helpful to show a wider scope of code and what are your objects

Comment: @GiladGreen I've update it.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve  *I want to have a list of Items order by votes* first retrieve all items and then order them by the described logic:

```
retrievedItems.OrderBy(item => item.ItemVotes.Sum(vote => vote.TypeVote ? 1 : -1));
```

In your current code of `_ItemsService.GetAll(x => x.ItemVotes)...` you lose the scope of knowing which vote belongs to which item and hence will get a single summary for all items together

Comment: like @michael_coxon's answer I've get two errors with you'r solution.

Comment: @mohammad Please show the context in which you are using the code.

Comment: I hope that I understood correctly. I use Unit of work like this example `http://techbrij.com/generic-repository-unit-of-work-entity-framework-unit-testing-asp-net-mvc`

Comment: @mohammad - please contain all context of question within StackOverflow. Please edit your question above to show what your current code looks like with how you use the answer and what error you get.

Comment: please see my question again

Comment: @mohammad - if you have your own wrapping classes you can't expect a standard linq line to just work as is. You need to update it. But see update answer

Comment: @mohammad - yap :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is sum the votes by mapping `true` values to `1` and `false` values to `-1`.

```
_ItemsService.GetAll(x => x.ItemVotes)
    .Sum(v => v.Vote ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: I've get two errors : cannot implicitly convert type `int` to `bool` and Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a variable `foo` where you have the items, then:

```
bar = foo.OrderBy(item => item.ItemVotes.Sum(vote => vote.TypeVote ? 1 : -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following in order to get a sorted list of items based on their votes with most positive voted items first.

Expose a method GetOrderedItems in your _ItemsService which will perform all the logic and return you the desired result instead of running your logic inside the caller to this service.

```
GetOrderedItems(Func<bool,int> predicate)
{
 return items.OrderByDescending(p => p.ItemVotes.Select(x => x.TypeVote).Sum(predicate)).ToList();        
}
```

In your call to the service you can pass in the selector like this:

```
Func<bool, int> getPositiveVotedItemsFirst = (vote) => vote ? 1 : -1;

var itemsOrderedByPositiveVotes = _ItemsService.GetOrderedItems(getHighlyVotedItems);
```

You could now easily get the items ordered by the least voted ones , just by changing your selector.

```
Func<bool, int> getLeastVotedItemsFirst = (vote) => !vote ? 1 : -1;

var itemsOrderedByNegativeVotes = _ItemsService.GetOrderedItems(getLeastVotedItemsFirst);
```